# ShapeShifter rotation using coordinates 0, 0, rather than center

Tags: android, animation, svg, vector

I'm trying to use shape shifter to create an animation https://shapeshifter.design/ but no matter what I do when I try to add a rotation animation to my vector (have tried many vectors some that I've created and some I've downloaded online) it rotates on the 0,0 coordinates rather than the center of my image.

steps to reproduce

1. Open shapeshifter
2. Select import svg
3. Select svg
4. Add a group layer and move the paths I'd like to rotate to this group
5. Add the rotation animation

Unless I'm missing something this should rotate the image

I also found Alex Lockwood has another shapeshifter tool https://beta.shapeshifter.design/ in which you can create the vector you want to animate and since my image is easy to reproduce I did exactly that but found the same results, so my question is how to rotate my vector (or any vector) around its center using shapeshifter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click on your group then change the `pivotX` and `pivotY` to the middle of the artboard.

[image]